# How to create a modal for rows in a table using Bootstrap 4

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am creating a table in an html file. The table is populated with data from a json file using ajax call. I am using datatable in bootstrap for loading data from json file. https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/ajax.html.
Now I want to open a modal on clicking a row in the table. The model part is not working. Also, I want to populate the modal with the data from the corresponding row. Can anyone please help me

The table part in table.html file is below:

```
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered responsive" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Location</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Phone no</th>
                                    <th>Start date</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                        </table>
                    </div>
```

The ajax call in demo.js file

```
      // Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dataTable").DataTable({
          ajax: "./data/newusers.json",
          columns: [
            { data: "name" },
            { data: "location" },
            { data: "email" },
            { data: "phone" },
            { data: "startdate" }
          ]
        });
      });
```

The json file is below:

```
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "location": "Bangalore",
            "email": "tiger.nixon@yahoo.com",
            "phone": "7896546789",
            "startdate": "2018/04/25"
          },
          {
            "name": "Garrett Winters",
            "location": "Goa",
            "email": "garrett.wint34@gmail.com",
            "phone": "6398764532",
            "startdate": "2018/07/25"
          }
        ]
      }
```

I tried this based on https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html

```
    // Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dataTable").DataTable({
        ajax: "./data/newusers.json",
        columns: [
        { data: "name" },
        { data: "location" },
        { data: "email" },
        { data: "phone" },
        { data: "startdate" }
        ],
        responsive: {
        details: {
            display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal({
            header: function(row) {
                var data = row.data();
                return "Details for " + data[0];
            }
            }),
            renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll({
            tableClass: "table"
            })
        }
        }
    });
    });
```

The above code is not working. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: "The model part is not working".. where have you attempted to define and open the modal? Have you tried: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html

Comment: @Themes.guide I have edited the question based on your comment

Comment: @Themes.guide Sorry unfortunately your solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ajax data with the DataTables responsive details modal display option, the "trick" is to **add an extra empty column** with `class="none"` for the modal trigger...

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone no</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th class="none"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

and then use the `column` type and target option to make clicking the `tr` row trigger the modal...

```
      responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column',
                target: 'tr',
                display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal({
                    header: function (row) {
                        var data = row.data();
                        return 'Details for ' + data.name;
                    }
                }),
                renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll({
                    tableClass: 'table'
                })
             }
      },...
```

[Demo of responsive details modal](https://www.codeply.com/go/jS2Q23xpJU)

---

Alternately, you can use a Bootstrap modal in the markup and its `show.bs.modal` event to populate the modal with data as needed using jQuery. The from the `row` render method can be passed using data attributes to the modal. With this method you have complete control over the modal content.

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 id="modalTitle"></h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
"columns": [
    ...
    { "data": "fieldname", "render": function(data, type, row) {return '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'+row.id+'" data-title="'+row.title+'" data-target="#myModal">'+data+'</button>'} },
    ...
],


$("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var triggerLink = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var id = triggerLink.data("id");
    var title = triggerLink.data("title");

    $("#modalTitle").text(title);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").html("<h5>id: "+id+"</h5>");
});
```

[Demo of custom Bootstrap modal](https://www.codeply.com/go/YV9eFnJXst)